# Form validation using JavaScript doesn't work with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem. Can someone help me to solve this problem? I don't know why the form validation using JavaScript worked well with HTML, but when did add the PHP, the form validation didn't work. For example, when I left the username blank or have a username start with numbers (which is not allowed), the form still submits successfully and saved the user input into the database successfully. Thank you for your help.

```js
var check_form=document.getElementById("registration");
var pattern=/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/gi;
var patternUsername=/^[A-Za-z]\w*$/;
function check(event){
    var userName=document.getElementById("username");
    var passWord=document.getElementById("password");
    var last_name=document.getElementById("lastName");
    var first_name=document.getElementById("firstName");
    var collegeName=document.getElementById("uni");
    var majorName=document.getElementById("majoring");
    event.preventDefault();
    if(userName.value==""){
        alert("User name needs to be specified");
        userName.focus();
    }
    else{
        if(!patternUsername.test(userName.value)){
            alert("Invalid username");
            userName.focus();
        }
    }
    if(passWord.value==""){
        alert("Password needs to be specified");
        first_name.focus();
    }
    else{
        if(passWord.length<8){
            alert("Password needs to be longer than 8 characters");
            passWord.focus();
        }
    }
    if(first_name.value==""){
        alert("First name needs to be specified");
        first_name.focus();
    }
    else{
        if(!pattern.test(first_name.value)){
            alert("First name does not allow number");
            first_name.focus();
        }
    }
    if(last_name.value==""){
        alert("Last name needs to be specified");
        last_name.focus();
    }
    else{
        if(!pattern.test(last_name.value)){
            alert("Last name does not allow number");
            last_name.focus();
        }
    }
    if(collegeName.value==""){
        alert("College name needs to be specified");
        userName.focus();
    }
    else{
        if(!pattern.test(collegeName.value)){
            alert("Invalid college name");
            collegeName.focus();
        }
    }
    if(majorName.value==""){
        alert("Major name needs to be specified");
        userName.focus();
    }
    else{
        if(!pattern.test(majorName.value)){
            alert("Invalid major name");
            majorName.focus();
        }
    }
    
    if(first_name.value!=="" && last_name.value!==""&&email!==""&&pattern.test(first_name.value)&&pattern.test(last_name.value)){
        alert("Perfect");
    }
}
check_form.addEventListener("submit",check);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Register</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./register.css">
        <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
        <style>
            form div{
                padding: 8px;
            }
        </style>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="registration" action="register.php" method="post">
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <div id='userName'>
                <label for="username">Username: </label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="user_name"><br>
            </div>
            <div id="passWord">
                <label for="password">Password: </label>
                <input type="text" id="password" name="pass"><br>
            </div>
            <div id='firstname'>
                <label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
                <input type="text" id="firstName" name="first_name"><br>
            </div>
            <div id="lastname">
                <label for="lastName">Last Name: </label>
                <input type="text" id="lastName" name="last_name"><br>
            </div>
            <div id="uniName">
                <label for="uni">College Name: </label>
                <input type="text" id="uni" name="uni"><br>
            </div>
            <div id="majorName">
                <label for="majoring">Major: </label>
                <input type="text" id="majoring" name="major"><br>
            </div>
            <br>
            <input id="buttonRegister" type="submit" name="register" value="Register"><br><br>
            <a href="./login.php">Already have an account?</a>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
   <?php
   session_start();
   require 'connect.php';
   if(isset($_POST['register'])){


$username = !empty($_POST['user_name']) ? trim($_POST['user_name']) : null;
$pass = !empty($_POST['pass']) ? trim($_POST['pass']) : null;
$firstName = !empty($_POST['first_name']) ? trim($_POST['first_name']) : null;
$lastName = !empty($_POST['last_name']) ? trim($_POST['last_name']) : null;
$collegeName = !empty($_POST['uni']) ? trim($_POST['uni']) : null;
$majorName = !empty($_POST['major']) ? trim($_POST['major']) : null;


$sql = "SELECT COUNT(user_name) AS num FROM users WHERE user_name = :username";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);


$stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);


$stmt->execute();


$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


if($row['num'] > 0){
   die('Username existed');
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, pass, first_name, last_name, uni, major) VALUES (:username, :password, :first_name, :last_name, :uni, :major)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);


$stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindValue(':password', $pass);
$stmt->bindValue(':first_name', $firstName);
$stmt->bindValue(':last_name', $lastName);
$stmt->bindValue(':uni', $collegeName);
$stmt->bindValue(':major', $majorName);


$result = $stmt->execute();


if($result){
    
    echo 'Thank you for registering with our website.';
}

}
?>
```

Comment: _"The structure of the file is the PHP and HTML are in one file"_ which one?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `if(passWord.value=="")` to `if(passWord.value==="")` (3 "=" instead of 2). If that works, set the rest of your `.value==""` to `.value===""`

Also, you have a logic error: `if(passWord.length<8)` should be set to `if(passWord.length<=8)` or `if(passWord.length<9)`.

Comment: I mean, the validation work with the HTML only. However, when I added the PHP, the validation doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

in your **< form >** element add onSubmit event example:

```js
var data=document.getElementById("f").value;
var validation=document.getElementById("p");

function tes(){

  if(data==""){
    validation.innerHTML ='cant leave data empty';
    return false;
  }else{
    return true;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return tes()">
<input name="data" id="f">
<p id="p"></p>
<input type="submit" name="send">
</form>
```

Comment: My JavaScript validation code works if there is no PHP, with the PHP, it doesn't work

Comment: that was happend when you not add submit event with return false,